# HC-05 emit data without pairing

Tags: arduino-nano, bluetooth, hc-05

Is it possible to emit data from an arduino connected to a hc-05 Bluetooth module without pairing it to another device?
i.e. imagine that I want to send a Bluetooth signal as if it was a information spot. Then whoever who gets the signal can read it.

Answer (score 2):

No. The HC-05 has to be paired. It runs on Bluetooth 2.x which requires pairing.  What you want is BLE (or Bluetooth 4.x) which has various "beacon" facilities.